# VueJS/jquery get value from P tag with button click

Tags: jquery, vue.js

I need to get the item price when I click button. This is my code currently :

```
   <div id="shop" class="row" v-cloak>
    {{#each items}}
        <img src="{{img}}">
        <p>{{title}}</p>
        <p class="price">{{price}}</p><br>
        <button class="btn btn-danger" @click="buyItem">Buy</button>
    {{/each}}
   </div>
```

JS:

```
    methods: {
        buyItem: function(event){    
            console.log($( event.target ).closest( ".price" ).text());
        }
    }
```

This returns me blank line in console.log. How do I get that `price` value ?

**EDIT**

server.js (getting items from here):

```
            res.render('game/index', {
                items
            });
```

Using moustache to display items:

index.hbs:

```
      <div id="shop" class="row" v-cloak>
    {{#each items}}
        <img src="{{img}}">
        <p>{{title}}</p>
        <p class="price">{{item.price}}</p><br>
        <button class="btn btn-danger" @click="buyItem">Buy</button>
    {{/each}}
      </div>
```

Comment: the ```.closest()``` method looks at an elements parents. you should try ```.prev()``` if you really want to use jquery.

Comment: @ry4nolson can't solve this without jquery... Is there option with vue ?

Comment: you can absolutely do this without jquery. See my answer below. You're combining invalid syntax along with improper Vue use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should pass the price as argument in your event handler:

```
... @click="buyItem(price)" ...
```

And your buyItem will become:

```
methods: {
        buyItem: function(price){    
            console.log(price);
        }
    }
```

Comment: What to do after that ? I created `price: null` in data and if I console.log it I get `null`

Answer (score 0):

See https://jsfiddle.net/mykwgo8x/1/.

```html
   <div id="shop" class="row" v-cloak>
      <!-- use v-for directive, not {{#each items}} -->
      <div v-for="item in items">
          <!-- <img src="{{item.img}}"> -->
          <!-- properties need to be accessed with "item." -->
          <p>{{item.title}}</p>
          <p class="price">{{item.price}}</p><br>
          <button class="btn btn-danger" @click="buyItem(item)">Buy</button>
      </div>
   </div>
```

```js
new Vue({
  el: "#shop",
  data: {
    items: [
      {
        title: "item 1",
        price : 10
      },
      { 
        title : "item 2",
        price: 2
      }
    ]
  },
  methods: {
    buyItem: function(item){
        console.log(item.price);
    }
  }
})
```

Comment: argh I get `item undefined` because I'm not using `v-for`. Should I make a class `item` for each item ?

Comment: are you actually using Vue? ```{{#each``` is not a loop in Vue. Use ```v-for``` to loop over the items in your Vue's data.

Comment: I'm using vue. But to get items from my back end server.js I need to fetch them like that with `{{#each`

Comment: that doesn't make any sense. ```{{#each``` is mustache syntax. That is not used by Vue. Post more code and maybe it will make sense. Does that template run on the backend?

Comment: I updated it. Well yes, what I should use instead with NodeJS ? Vuetify  ?

Comment: Ahh I solved it. I just pass the price to the `@click="buyItem({{price}})` and I get the price in the function. Above answer does the trick